# What happens when you invoke new Object()?

Tags: java, object

I was trying to figure out what happens when you create an Object but I didn't find an  Object() constructor method in Object.java, even if the documentation says that Object() exists.

Comment: In Java every class if not define constructor(s) there is already one that is null argument.

Comment: @Asad Rasheed It could still be a protected or private constructor. Why is it public? Second thought: Maybe the construct needs to be public so you can instantiate an array of Objects?

Comment: @Jeremy: As Java defines it implicitly so It should be least restricted. this is my opinion might wrong for this statement.

Comment: But if a class hasn't a explicit constructor, the constructor of the superclass is invoked... until you reach Object()... but I can't find an Object() method in Object.java

Comment: Well, the JVM do create the object (zero the memory,unless the page/memory has been zero'd already), initializes the object header (it might incl. class info, lock info, System.identityHashCode placeholder, etc) and return the reference to you. Where the memory resides and how is allocated should be considered an impl. detail but most JVMs will attempt to allocate the object very cheaply but just bumping a pointer (aka thread local memory storage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object does indeed have a no-arg constructor, You can see it by dumping the byte code for the class, using

```
javap -v java.lang.Object


public java.lang.Object();
Code:
Stack=0, Locals=1, Args_size=1
0:  return
LineNumberTable: 
line 20: 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Object object = new Object();
```

That is perfectly valid code. It essentially does nothing. The only use I've seen with it is using it as a lock:

```
int c = 0;
Object lock = new Object();

...

synchronized(lock) { 
    c++;
}
```

Comment: That wasn't (quite) the question.

Comment: new Object() aside lock can be used as key or sentinel value, there are even more options to utilize the returned pointer, yet there are all out of the scope of the discussion. Good thing is that the pointer is 100% unique and that's important.

Comment: Ah... reread the question again and realized he was looking at the source code. Didn't quite catch that before. Just thought he was trying to create a new object.